# MS Access linked table displays short text instead of Decimal data type

Tags: sql-server-2017, ms-access, odbc

I have linked tables in MS Access databases (various versions, 2007-2019) which are connected to SQL server 2017 via Sql server 2017 drivers (eg, msodbcsql_17.2.0.1_x64). Fields that are of data type Decimal(38,20) in SQL server are showing as type Short Text in the linked tables.

According to the [Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/comparing-access-and-sql-server-data-types-9188f41d-6c0e-4733-9d20-d08916f50bd2?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), the data types are directly comparable.

Why might this be coming through as a different data type?

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that even though the data types are directly comparable, the data precision is not. Access can handle a max precision of 28, hence why the conversion into short text.